# Graph algorithm to find all subgraphs that connect N arbitrary vertices

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have an graph with the following attributes:

- Undirected
- Not weighted
- Each vertex has a minimum of 2 and maximum of 6 edges connected to it.
- Vertex count will be < 100
- Graph is static and no vertices/edges can be added/removed or edited.

I'm looking for **all** subgraphs between a random subset of the vertices (at least 2).

I've created a (warning! programmer art) animated gif to illustrate what i'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgaq5.gif

My end goal is to have a set of subgraphs that allow moving from one of the subset vertices (blue nodes) and reach **any** of the other subset vertices (blue nodes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the paper

*Generating all the Steiner trees and computing Steiner intervals for a fixed number of terminals*

by Costa Dourado, de Oliveira,  and Protti is what you want (available from ScienceDirect). I think the paper gives an algorithm for generating all the *minimal* (under subgraph inclusion) subgraphs connecting the blue vertices (from which it is easy to obtain all such subgraphs).

Comment: My understanding was that Steiner trees introduce intermediate vertices and edges? My graph is fixed, does this algorithm give the subgraphs without adding vertices or edges?

Comment: You're a little vague on exactly what kind of subgraphs you're looking for, but the examples in your image seem to be including intermediate vertices.

Comment: I'm rapidly moving out of my depth it appears but my understanding was that Steiner trees create vertices that would not of been in the original graph. Is a Steiner node (in relation to graphs) in fact any node that is in the original graph but not a terminal node? 

Comment: Given a graph G and a subset of terminal vertices X of G, a *Steiner tree* is a connected subgraph of G which contains X. Thus, you simply want to enumerate all Steiner trees where X is your set of blue vertices. And yes, the *Steiner nodes* are nodes in the original graph which are not terminal nodes. 

Comment: russtbarnacle, a Steiner tree in geometry is a slightly different concept than a Steiner tree in a graph, and what you're looking for is indeed a Steiner tree in a graph.  (The Wikipedia page on Steiner trees describes both.)

Comment: I am not sure whether you are looking only for (cardinality) minimal such subgraphs -those are Steiner trees - or for all subgraph connecting selected vertices - you can expect to have an incredible amount of such graphs. The paper cited is wrong (but not that hard to repair) and claims to enumerate all Steiner subgraph.